# The meaning of "clearing products or supplies through customs"

Tags: meaning

This is a quote from an anti-corruption manual. The quote says

> The company may not offer or provide a gift, meal, entertainment, travel
>   expenses or other corporate hospitality to a Public Official or commercial
>   counterparty as an incentive, or in exchange or as a reward, for granting a
>   regulatory request, **clearing products or supplies through customs**, or providing
>   any other improper benefit or improper advantage to the Company.

Does the word "clearing" mean "**giving permission**" or "**removing**"? I think the meaning must be "giving permission".

What's the meaning of that phrase? Does it mean "a public official granted permission for the company's products/supplies through customs department"?

Comment: What is ‘cleared’ is the impediment to the movement of the goods across a border; or we can say the goods are cleared of the impediment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your goods are *cleared* through customs, you are allowed to take them into the country.

This comes up in a discussion of corruption because it is common in some countries for the customs officers to expect bribes before they will clear your goods and allow them to enter their country (where you might want to sell them, for example).

So it is a "giving permission" for the goods to enter a country but it is also a "removing" because it allows you to remove the goods from the customs office and take them somewhere you can make more money on them.